# Prove that a simple graph with $n \ge 2$ and at least $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ edges is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The problem consists of three parts, but I could only figure out the very first part:
Suppose that $G$ is a simple graph with $n\ge2$ vertices and at least $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ edges.
(a) Show that G cannot cantain an isolated vertex.
(b) Suppose that $n\ge3$, and that $G$ is not connected. Show that removing any vertex from $G$ will result in a graph with at least $\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}+1$ edges.
(c) Using the results in (a) and (b), prove by induction that $G$ must be connected.
I proved (a) by contradiction, explaining that if an isolated vertex exists in $G$, $G$ would have at most $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ edges.
However, I have no idea how to proceed to step (b). I couldn't even come up with a $G$ that satisfy the conditions of (b).

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: An alternate proof strategy: if $G$ is the disconnected union of a $k$-vertex graph and an $(n-k)$-vertex graph, then it has at most $\binom k2 + \binom{n-k}2$ edges; this is maximized when $k=1$ or $k=n-1$, in which case the bound on the number of edges is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) Any vertex is connected to at most $n-2$ edges because $G$ is not connected so $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1-(n-2)=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}+1$

(c) Suppose $G$ with $n$ vertices is not connected and have at least $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ edges then remove a vertex we have a not connected graph with $n-1$ vertices and at least $\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}+1$ edges contradicting our induction hypothesis for $n-1$ case.

Comment: Could you explain more on point (c), I don't quite get it.

Comment: Your induction hypothesis is any graph with $n-1$ vertices and have at least $\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}+1$ edges is connected. Now given any $n$ vertices graph, we assume it has $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+1$ edges and is not connected and derive a contradiction. We remove one vertex and from part (b) we know the remaining graph has at least $\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}+1$ edges. Now this contradicts our induction hypothesis because the original graph has no isolated vertex so after removing a vertex the graph is still not connected but our hypothesis says it is connected.

Comment: Why do we even needed part a) . part b) + induction is sufficient enough ?